# override the triggers for (managed) npsp pack

Tags: managed-package, npsp

I am unable to inactive the default managed trigger in NPSP pack of salesforce

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Nonprofit Success Pack uses Table-Driven Trigger Management (TDTM). You manage NPSP triggers by manipulating Trigger Handler records, which the TDTM framework interprets to control trigger functionality activation and deactivation.

TDTM is [covered](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-TDTM-Overview) in the NPSP  documentation, including information about how to [disable](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Disable-Trigger-Handlers) trigger handlers.

Answer (score 4):

The NPSP uses table driven trigger managment. You have to edit their settings in the tables that control them. How to deactivate a trigger is covered in [Disable Trigger Handlers for NPSP](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Disable-Trigger-Handlers)

From the documentation:

> It's helpful to know what each of the Apex classes do, so that you know which Trigger Handlers to disable. Visit [NPSP Codebase Documentation](http://developer.salesforce.org/Cumulus/ApexDocumentation/) for a description of the Apex classes managed by TDTM—classes with the _TDTM extension in the name. Note that there are some classes that are not managed by TDTM, such as utility and settings classes.
>
> Important
>
> Be careful when changing Trigger Handler records. They're designed to work in conjunction, and changing or disabling them can lead to undesirable results. Always test in a Sandbox environment before changing Trigger Handlers in production!

Note that to access the above documenatation you'll need to create a login for the Power of Us hub.

Answer (score 1):

One additional suggestion I would add - the docs say to create a Tab\List View:

> You can't use the NPSP Settings page to disable TDTM Trigger Handlers.
>   To directly edit the Trigger Handler records, create a custom Tab and
>   List View for the Trigger Handler object.

But I always find it easier to go to the Trigger Object definition, enable reports for it and then create a simple report of the records in the trigger object. Then can just run a report to see all the record, and then go to an individual record's detail screen to make it inactive.

e.g
**Enable reports on Trigger Object**
[image: Enable reports on Trigger Object]

**Build report on user managed records on trigger object**
[image: Build report on triggers]

**Click through to detail page to edit, uncheck active etc.**
[image: view detail page and uncheck active]

Comment: As a Newbie how can i do it in npsp as I have view all available options but there is not a single button to disable the triggers